# libgit2 - what is the correct install prefix?

Tags: libgit2

I'm following the install instructions for libgit2 as specified in its README.md file.

What is the correct directory to specify as the "install prefix"?

Here is the relevant extract from README.md:

```
The `libgit2` library is built using [CMake](<http://www.cmake.org>) (version 2.6 or newer) on all platforms.

On most systems you can build the library using the following commands

        $ mkdir build && cd build
        $ cmake ..
        $ cmake --build .

Alternatively you can point the CMake GUI tool to the CMakeLists.txt file and generate platform specific build project or IDE workspace.

To install the library you can specify the install prefix by setting:

        $ cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/install/prefix
        $ cmake --build . --target install
```

Comment: FTR, there is nothing libgit2-specific about this. The installation prefix is the same as in every other build system for any app/library.

Comment: @CarlosMartinNieto it's a pity libgit2 doesn't set this to a sane default, cost me many hours to work this out when it should have just gone ahead and installed to the most likely location.

Comment: It would be CMake doing so, and it does, if you don't specify anything, it tries to install to `/usr/local/` which is the correct default for user-installed programs and libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose whatever directory you like. You just need to make sure that you have write permissions on that directory. In addition to this when you want to build another program against your build of libgit2, you have to instruct its build-system to look for headers and library files in the folder where you installed libgit2. Similarly if you want to run another program using the shared libgit2-library of your build, you have to add the corresponding folder of your libgit2 installation to the corresponding search path of your OS (i.e. in case of Linux you can set the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH). If you do not specify a installation-directory explicitly I assume the default is `/usr` or `/usr/local`. In that case you may not need additional configuration for building or running other programs using your libgit2 as these paths are typically already included in the corresponding setup.